# Iterator mediator counter esb wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-data-services-server

I'm using the iterate mediator for calculate the sum of a note variable i tried with the script mediator
but when i send the api in postman for test we takes a long time without answer and i have this error :

```
ERROR {PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor} - Unable to find axis service for service name : studenttest/getsomme
```

here is my code:

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/gettotal">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="$url:nom" name="uri.var.nom" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="http://ITMTNF3RRJSJ:8290/services/studenttest/getsomme?nom={uri.var.nom}">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <property name="it_count" scope="operation" type="STRING" value="0"/>
            <iterate expression="//symbols/symbol" sequential="TRUE">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.note)" name="note" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <script language="js"><![CDATA[var note = mc.getProperty('note');
 var totalnote =it_count+note;
 mc.setProperty('it_count', totalnote);]]></script>
                </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Does the Dataservice work when you directly invoke it? `GET http://ITMTNF3RRJSJ:8290/services/studenttest/getsomme?nom=1234`

Answer (score 0):

This error "Unable to find axis service for service name" is a known issue[1] when a data service is invoked as a Rest service with query parameters in MI-1.2.0 and this is already fixed in MI-1.2.0 with the latest updates. If you have a valid wso2 subscription you can get the latest updates using the Update 2.0 tool[2].

However, you can invoke the data service in soap manner or rest manner without query parameters and check the mediation.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/issues/2351

[2] https://updates.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/